# Is it good to replace broadcast receiver with Greenrobot Eventbus for triggering event based functions and data transfer from service to activity?

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-broadcast, greenrobot-eventbus

I have implemented a service, where I handle the state changes(connect, disconnect, onServiceDiscoverd, onCharacteristicChange etc) and receiving data from another device through gatt Server.

My question is, Can the events be handled efficiently using **Greenrobot Eventbus** replacing broadcast receiver **between service and Activity**?

Comment: I have not used Greenrobot Eventbut so I can not comment on that. But in general, if the communication is between activity and service of the same process, it is better to use LocalBroadcastManager rather than BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @kmaini is there any example or link that you came across that's very useful to you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unlike LocalBroadcastManager, EventBus is more simple to use. You only go via 3 steps:

1- Create an event class. A simple Java class that represent the response when 
the action occur.

2- Register the event bus as a subscriber in your Activity onCreate method

```
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And of course, unregister it in your Activity onDestroy method

```
 EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

3- The subscribing method is created in the same activity that registered for the EventBus. Example in WorkOrderActivity

```
   @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(EventClass event)
```

*When the event occur, you should call the post method, passing the event object you created before.*

```
  EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventClass (Data));
```

As kmaini mentioned, you can replace it with LocalBroadcastManager, but you will have to map the data from the intent by yourself. Unlike EventBus which can pass objects.

Also, greenrobot, the creators of EventBus Library, answered this question [here](https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/):

> Q: How's EventBus different to Android's BroadcastReceiver/Intent
>   system?
>
> A: Unlike Android's BroadcastReceiver/Intent system,  EventBus uses
>   standard Java classes as events and offers  a more convenient API.
>   EventBus is intended for a lot more  uses cases where you wouldn't
>   want to go through the hassle  of setting up Intents, preparing Intent
>   extras, implementing  broadcast receivers, and extracting Intent
>   extras again.  Also, EventBus comes with a much lower overhead.

Answer (score 1):

From another perspective, I believe broadcast managers in Android uses main thread handler's message queue to process events. So, if you are free to use a different thread (if you have no-UI events/jobs/tasks) with a proper queue (like using another HandlerThread) then you can take advantage of using that thread's specific queue to process your jobs, without interfering UI events and mixing your stuff with UI work. You can also play with the thread's priority value to balance the work.

Now, if GreenRobot provides that all functionality in a few lines of code, then I would definitely try it to see any performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

EventBus makes things much easier because you can pass is arbitrary Java objects along in the event.You not do the same with `Intents` because your object has to implement `Parcelable` and the "tedious" parcelable implementation which is something you might not what to do on an existing code base.