# How to make Eventbus run in background with BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver, greenrobot-eventbus

How to i make `Greenrobot Eventbus` get register or running in the background with `BroadcastReceiver`?

I try it but its only work when the `Activity` or app is open when i close the app the `Eventbus` is stop!

I use Greenrobot Eventbus to call `method` on `Activity` from `BroadcastReceiver`.

Any suggest or better way to use other code?

Comment: You can check answers in both these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141091/is-it-good-to-replace-broadcast-receiver-with-greenrobot-eventbus-for-triggering) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250510/how-to-receive-eventbus-events-when-activity-is-in-the-background)

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement it like this,

In your Activity's onResume method, register for events:

`EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`

And unregister at onPause

`EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);`

Finally, implement the activity's behavior for getting the info:

`@Subscribe
public void onEvent(Intent intent) {
    // do something
}`

Make sure that your Subscribe method is **public** otherwise it will not be called.

Please tell me If you have any query.

Comment: Didnt work the activity close after calling method and Eventbus stop too!